# I can't find a way to convert a pandas timestamp into a date for a matplotlib graph

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, datetime, matplotlib

I've been trying countless times for the past few days and I can't seem to find a solution.

Here's my **current code** with some comments:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
import datetime
import pandas_datareader.data as web
import matplotlib.ticker as ticker
from mpl_finance import candlestick2_ohlc
from matplotlib.dates import (MONDAY, DateFormatter, MonthLocator,
                              WeekdayLocator, date2num)



# Define start and end date
end = datetime.datetime.now()
start = end - datetime.timedelta(days=63)

# Load data for the specific stock
quotes = web.DataReader('AAPL', 'yahoo', start, end)
quotes['Date'] = quotes.index
# Order the dataframe
quotes = quotes[['Date','Open', 'High', 'Low', 'Close']]
#          2019-09-16  217.729996  220.130005  217.559998  219.899994    

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
candlestick2_ohlc(  ax,
                    quotes['Open'], 
                    quotes['High'],
                    quotes['Low'], 
                    quotes['Close'],
                    width=0.5,
                    colorup='g',
                    colordown='r')

#ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(ticker.MaxNLocator(8))#I was just testing with this

def mydate(x,pos):
    try: 
        a = quotes['Date'][int(x)]
        # print(a) --> 2019-11-04 00:00:00  
        # type(a) --> <class 'pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timestamp'>
        a = pd.to_datetime(a) # doesn't work
        return a
    except IndexError:
        return ''

ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(ticker.FuncFormatter(mydate))

fig.autofmt_xdate()
fig.tight_layout()        
plt.show()
```

And this is **the output**:

[image]

As you can see, it shows the date like this: **2019-11-04 00:00:00**

**My goal** is to show the date like this:

[image]

I have cleaned up the code as much as I could to make it easier to read and understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the Python documentation on dates:

https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/datetime.html

You are looking for

```
return '{:%b}'.format(a)
```

Answer (score 2):

to_datetime has been deprecated ...

try using :

```
a = a.date()
```

Or

```
to_pydatetime()
```